# Defining a #selector method when it can't access a programmatically created UILabel

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel, selector, viewdidload

If you define a UILabel programmatically, it must be done so in `viewDidLoad()`? But, if you were to define a `#selector` method that needed to set said label, it would be impossible given that the `@objc` selector method needs to be outside the scope of the `viewDidLoad()` method, where it cannot access the label. How do you get around this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
    var count = 4
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
                
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 430)
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 130)
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: <#T##Selector#>, userInfo: <#T##Any?#>, repeats: <#T##Bool#>)
        
        
        @objc func updateLabel() { // ERROR @objc can only be used with members of classes...
            if count > 0 {
                count -= 1
                label.text = "\(count)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "If you define a UILabel programmatically, it must be done so in viewDidLoad()." That's not true. Can you show some code that's not working? And explain how it is not working, including the desired behaviour. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @Sweeper Hi. I did add the code. It's for a simple timer defined programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you have put the selector `updateLabel` *inside* of `viewDidLoad`. You should put it outside `viewDidLoad` so that it is a member of your class, rather than a local function.

To access the label in `updateLabel`, simply move the declaration of the label outside of both methods.

You should also add a `timer` parameter to `updateLabel` so that you can stop the timer when `count` reaches 0, rather than keeping the timer running forever.

```
var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 430)
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 130)
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(label)
    
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateLabel(_ timer: Timer) {
    if count > 0 {
        count -= 1
        label.text = "\(count)"
    } else {
       timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I understand that. I left it there on purppse. That's actually what my original question was about - I cannot access the label from *outside* viewDidLoad().

Comment: @AbdulBasitShaikh You should declare `label` outside of both methods, like in my edited answer.